# How to apply Gauss' law in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Suppose I have 3 charges $-4e, -6e$ and $+10e$ and these 3 charges are placed on the corners of an asymmetric triangle (which means all the sides have different lengths and the angles between them are also different). Now we imagine a spherical shell which encloses this charge distribution. I want to calculate the electric field on the surface of the triangle. Can I apply Gauss' law to do that? As the charge distribution is not symmetric, $\vec{E}$ won't come outside the integral I suppose. So how can I do that using Gauss' law?

Comment: It'd be better to sum a few $kq/r$ terms, each with its own $r$ expressible in terms of the coordinates of a point at which you'll compute the potential.

Comment: What the spherical shell has to do with the field in the plane of the triangle? Or is not the field for points in the plane the one you want to calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauss's Law cannot be practically used to calculate the electric field at a point on the Gaussian sphere you describe, because the value of $\vec E$ is different for different points on the sphere. In fact, as the charge distribution of this configuration does not possess sufficient symmetry, the use of Gauss's law is not practical, and we cannot find any other closed surface surrounding this distribution that could make it's use practical.

This does not mean that Gauss's law does not apply for the surface you describe. It does, but it's not practical and cannot be easily simplified further.

Comment: Can I make any changes in the Gaussian surface so that using Gauss' law, I can find the electric field. Actually in my PhD interview, the interviewer was quite adamant that without changing the charge distribution, I am allowed to do anything, assume any Gaussian surface so that the electric field can be derived from there. I couldn't get it. Is there any way to modify the surface so that I will be able to calculate $\vec{E}$?

Comment: @SAGARMODAK None that I am aware of. A scalene triangle simply lacks the symmetry needed to apply Gauss's law practically. There are no Gaussian surfaces that I can think of which can have (1) A constant value of E or (2) Portions where E = 0 or (3) Portions where E and dA are parallel (or perpendicular). For the most part, a surface that can satisfy atleast one of these three characteristics could benefit from Gauss's law. As pointed out by J.G, it is simply better to add up $\frac{k_e.q}{r^2} \hat{r}$ values for this particular charge distribution.

Comment: Now I got your point.

Answer (score 2):

For any enclosed charge, whether symmetrical or asymmetrical, Gauss' Law gives you the net flux across the surface.

If the charge is sufficiently symmetrical, you can apply the law to give you the electric field at any point of the Gaussian surface. Examples of the application of the law for this purpose can be found on the fourth slide here:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gaulaw.html

But if the charge distribution lacks sufficient symmetry for the application of Gauss' law, then the field must be found by summing the point charge fields of individual charge elements. That's the situation you have with the 3 charges in your example.

Hope this helps.